# How to solve $\lim_{t \to 0}\frac{\frac{1}{|a+th|}(a+th) - \frac{1}{|a|}a}{t}$

Tags: calculus, limits

Title really says it all.

I'm trying to compute this limit. It is the differential of the function $f(x) =  \frac{x}{|x|}$ in the direction $h$.

So in our limit $\lim_{t \to 0}\frac{\frac{1}{|a+th|}(a+th) - \frac{1}{|a|}a}{t}$ we have that $a, h \in \mathbb R^n, |a| \neq 0, |h| = 1$, $t \in \mathbb R$.

This should be equal to $\frac{h}{|a|} - \frac{a \langle a, h\rangle}{|a|^3}$ if the answer provided is to be believed.

We could try to verify this by actually computing $\frac{df_i}{dt}(a+th)$ at $t = 0$ but that hardly seems pleasant.

Comment: i would distinguish the cases $$x>0,x=0$$ and $$x<0$$

Comment: but i meant the limit for $x$ tends to zero, sorry

Comment: Yeah I just got that. I'll try. How would you treat $x = 0$?

Comment: im not sure the limit is well define because in the case n = 1 and a > 0 , h > 0 as im allowed to assume then there is no limit (in the finite meaning)

Comment: Use the [definition](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DirectionalDerivative.html) $\nabla_{h} f \equiv \nabla f \cdot \frac{h}{|h|}$. You would need to compute the partial derivatives

Comment: There has to be a limit. Even in the one dimensional case, $f(x) = \frac{x}{|x|}$ is differentiable for all $x \neq 0$.

Comment: @Winther I want to avoid computing the partial derivatives if at all possible. And what I use is actually the definition of directional derivative. Those two things are equivalent.

Comment: @I think your notation and wording are rather sloppy. First, you should say this is a function $\;f: \Bbb R^n\to\Bbb R^n\;$ , second: what you want is the *directional derivative* of at a point $\;\vec 0\neq\vec a\in\Bbb R^n\;$ in the direction of the origin $\;\vec 0\in\Bbb R^n\;$ ...

Comment: In the direction $\;\vec0\neq\vec h\in\Bbb R^n\;$, of course. The above was a typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you define the function $\;f:\Bbb R^n\to\Bbb R^n\,,\,\,f(x)=\frac x{\left\|x\right\|}\;$ , we then have

$$f(x)=\left(\frac{x_1}{\sqrt{\sum\limits_{k=1}^n x_k^2}}\,,\,\,\frac{x_2}{\sqrt{\sum\limits_{k=1}^n x_k^2}}\,,\ldots,\,\frac{x_n}{\sqrt{\sum\limits_{k=1}^n x_k^2}}\right)\implies$$$${}$$

$$\nabla f_x=\left(\frac{\sum\limits_{k\neq 1}^nx_k^2}{\left(\sum\limits_{k=1}^n x_k^2\right)^{3/2}}\,,\,\,\frac{\sum\limits_{k\neq 2}^nx_k^2}{\left(\sum\limits_{k=1}^n x_k^2\right)^{3/2}},\,\ldots,\,\frac{\sum\limits_{k\neq n}^nx_k^2}{\left(\sum\limits_{k=1}^n x_k^2\right)^{3/2}}\right)$$

Observe all the partial derivatives of first order exist and are continuous in some neighborhood of $\;a\;$ , thus the directional derivative at $\;a\;$ in the direction of $\;h\;$ is given by derivative is given by

$$\nabla f_a\cdot\frac h{\left\|h\right\|}$$

Try to take it from here.

Answer (score 1):

Note that by [binomial series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series#Binomial_series)

$$|a+th|=\langle a+th, a+th\rangle^\frac12=(|a|^2+2t\langle a, h\rangle+t^2)^\frac12=\\=|a|\left(1+\frac{2t\langle a, h\rangle}{|a|^2}+\frac{t^2}{|a|^2}\right)^\frac12=|a|+\frac{t\langle a, h\rangle}{|a|}+o(t^2)$$

thus

$$\frac{\frac{1}{|a+th|}(a+th) - \frac{1}{|a|}a}{t}=\frac{|a|(a+th)-|a+th|a}{t|a||a+th|}=\frac{|a|a+t|a|h-|a|a-\frac{t\langle a, h\rangle}{|a|}a+o(t^2)}{t|a|^2+o(t^2)}=\frac{|a|h-\frac{\langle a, h\rangle}{|a|}a+o(t)}{|a|^2+o(t)}\to \frac{h}{|a|}-\frac{\langle a, h\rangle}{|a|^3}a$$